# Is it possible to get gmail contacts list using Gmail API (.NET)?

Tags: .net, google-api, gmail-api

I need to get the list of contacts and after that send a message to one of the contacts. Can I get a list of gmail contacts without using Google Contacts API, only with Gmail API?

Comment: I believe that's not possible because Google provides Contacts specific data through their Contacts API only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the guides and have not seen methods to fetch gmail contacts. I think retrieving contacts was deliberately meant for [Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) given it has methods such as (which doesn't exist in Gmail API) :

*Retrieving a single contact*

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I know about Google Contacts api but, as I understood its unreal to get contacts without that one,+1 for help